# how to get all product collection order by product name in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to get the product collection order by product name in magento? any idea??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get all products sorted by product name ascending:-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

Get all products sorted by product name descending:-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'DESC');
```

Get limited number of products (for example: 10 products) sorted by product name ascending:-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                         ->setPageSize(10);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

see in [Magento Wiki](http://magento.com/help/documentation)

Comment: FYI, your link is invalid now.